# How to collect data from attributes from child component Angular 2

Tags: angular, components, ionic2, collect

So the problem is how to collect data from attributes in child components in template to parent component.
Parent template looks like this:

```
<ion-content>
  <blocks-banners-slideshow class="contentBlock" [zone]="'main'" [slideOptions]="{loop:true}"></blocks-banners-slideshow>
  <blocks-catalog-category class="contentBlock" [root]="0"></blocks-catalog-category>
  <blocks-catalog-topproducts class="contentBlock" [dirs]="[0]" ></blocks-catalog-topproducts>
</ion-content>
```

I have components blocks-banners-slideshow, blocks-catalog-category, blocks-catalog-topproducts. 
I need to loop somehow all this components to collect data from attributes - [zone], [root], [dirs] and etc in my parent component.

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access them via `ViewChild`.

Give your childs names, or use the type instead:

```
<ion-content>
  <blocks-banners-slideshow #bbs class="contentBlock" [zone]="'main'" [slideOptions]="{loop:true}"></blocks-banners-slideshow>
  <blocks-catalog-category #bcc class="contentBlock" [root]="0"></blocks-catalog-category>
  <blocks-catalog-topproducts #bct class="contentBlock" [dirs]="[0]" ></blocks-catalog-topproducts>
</ion-content>
```

And in your component:

```
@ViewChild('bbs') bbs1: BlocksBannersSlideshowComponent;
@ViewChild(BlocksBannersSlideshowComponent) bbs2: BlocksBannersSlideshowComponent;

@ViewChild('bcc') bcc1: BlocksCatalogCategoryComponent;
@ViewChild(BlocksCatalogCategoryComponent) bcc2: BlocksCatalogCategoryComponent;
...
```

Those variables are accessible after this event was fired: `ngAfterViewInit()` !

Or use `ViewChildren` for dynamically added Components:

```
@ViewChildren(BlocksBannersSlideshowComponent) bbsChilds: QueryList<BlocksBannersSlideshowComponent>;

@ViewChildren(BlocksCatalogCategoryComponent) bccChilds: QueryList<BlocksCatalogCategoryComponent>;
...
```

And subscribe to those querylists inside of `ngAfterViewInit()`:

```
this.bssChilds.changes.subscribe(...);
```

Comment: It'is a good idea. Thank you. But what if the template is create on web server dinamicaly?

Comment: And Do you know how to loop components in parent component?

Comment: loop? what components do you want to loop?

Comment: All that is inside ion-content tag because the template can be changed dynamicaly from outside.

Comment: Ok, I got it.. I don't know if it's possible to get all those child's.. You could use `ElementRef` for this, but you don't have those Components then.. You have just the HTML elements.

Comment: I was tried ElementRef. That is not possible because the attributes of  ng-reflection's full of [Object object] but it is in Strings. Maybe you are familiar with ViewChildren? Any Ideas?

Comment: If you know which are the Types of possible Childs you can use `ViewChildren`, sure!

Comment: Thank you very much